# Flashing DBAN from linux

Tags: linux, usb-flash-drive, flash, dban

I need to flash DBAN on a USB-Drive for work to wipe some hard drives. Also I am creating a "tutorial" on how to use DBAN for my colleagues but I ran into a problem. Our computers run on Linux and I can't figure out how to flash DBAN to USB on Linux. I tried it on a Windows PC using Rufus and that worked, but everytime I flash it from Linux it gives me "Error 1962: No operating system found".

I've already tried different USB-Drives, formatting the partitions to different file systems, using different flashing tools like balena etcher, unetbootin, even Universal USB Installer. The DD method also doesn't work for me and trying different BIOS settings also didn't do anything, the computer just won't boot from the USB.

Maybe someone here can help me find a solution, thanks.